# .NET Framework - WCF - MTOM - Prevent Multipart/Related

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, .net-framework-version, mtom

All,

I want to consume a SOAP XML service requiring MTOM to transfer files as attachments.
I'm only controlling the initiator, not the server side. When consuming the service .NET Framework converts the message automatically to a multipart message while the server side does not support this (and cannot be modified within my control).
I can't find the threshold when this behaviour is applied and I'm also not able to find the settings allowing me to prevent this.
The size of the attached documents is limited, so a simple format application/xop+xml shouldn't result in any issues or performance penalties.

Some code snippets:

```
var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(GetUri());
var binding = new WSHttpBinding();
binding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Mtom;
var stackOverflowChannel = ChannelFactory<MyInterface>.CreateChannel(binding, endpointAddress);

stackOverflowChannel.ConsumeMe(request);
```

All the help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your response.
Yesterday evening I've found the issue...
Apparantely when transferring a message using MTOM it's always send as a multipart message. There is a hardcoded boundary in the Microsoft DLLs that switches to multipart starting from 767 bytes. This is in the XmlMtomWriter.cs.
Code snippet:

```
    class XmlMtomWriter : XmlDictionaryWriter, IXmlMtomWriterInitializer
    {
        // Maximum number of bytes that are inlined as base64 data without being MTOM-optimized as xop:Include
        const int MaxInlinedBytes = 767;  // 768 will be the first MIMEd length

        int maxSizeInBytes;
        XmlDictionaryWriter writer;
        XmlDictionaryWriter infosetWriter;
        MimeWriter mimeWriter;
```

This value is hardcoded and cannot be overwritten, unless you would create your own serialization factory.

The issue in my case was a non-issue... The server side had a bug in their validation code, which assumed that it had to be "SINGLE format" in case an attachement was sent.

By reconfiguring their end, I was able to walk around their bug and now everything works as expected.

The server side was the XDSToolkit (XDSTools).

It was not a security issue, as the communication did succeed.

Thank you for your answer and time.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if the server enable `MTOM` encoder, then the client code you write above will work properly. Another thing to note is that `Wshttpbinding` uses message layer security by default, and requires the client to provide windows credentials.

```
//logins account on the server side.
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "administrator";
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "abcd1234!";
```

At last, I advise you to call the remote service by using a client proxy.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/accessing-services-using-a-wcf-client
By `adding the service reference` tool, the client-side generates a proxy class in `Reference.cs` and configuration files for service. The configuration file is located in `appconfig/webconfig`, and the binding configuration it contains is consistent with the server. We can use this method to determine the configuration of the server (whether it supports `Mtom`).
On my client-side, It works as expected.

```
ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
            //logins account on the server side.
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "administrator";
            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "abcd1234!";
            Console.WriteLine(client.Test());
```

SOAP message captured by Fiddler.
[image]
I would like to know the error details of calling the remote service, Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.